# How to fix the Exception: Saving data in the Hive serde table Please use the insertInto() API as an alternative. Spark:2.1.0

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

We are trying to save Dataframe to a Hive Table using the `saveAsTable()` method. But, We are getting the below exception. We are trying to store the data as `TextInputFormat`.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Saving data in the Hive serde table `cdx_network`.`inv_devices_incr` is not supported yet. Please use the insertInto() API as an alternative..;


reducedFN.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("cdx_network.alert_pas_incr");
```

I tried `insertInto()` and also `enableHiveSupport()` and it works. But, I want to use `saveAsTable()` .

I want to understand why the `saveAsTable()` does not work. I tried going through the documentation and also the code. Did not get much understanding. It supposed to be working. I have seen issues raised by people who are using Parquet format but for TextFileInputFormat i did not see any issues.

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `cdx_network.alert_pas_incr`(
  `alertid` string,
  `alerttype` string,
  `alert_pas_documentid` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'maprfs:/apps/cdx-dev/alert_pas_incr'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='{\"BASIC_STATS\":\"true\"}',
  'numFiles'='0',
  'numRows'='0',
  'rawDataSize'='0',
  'totalSize'='0',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1524121971')
```

Comment: Did you try to use insertInto method? And does enableHiveSupport() is active in your sparkSession?

Comment: Hey @DanilaZharenkov i have updated the post.

Comment: can your show the output of 'show create table cdx_network.alert_pas_incr'? Does this table partitioned? Is 'reducedFN'  RDD or Dataset/Dataframe?

Comment: yes 'reducedFN' is a Dataset.

Comment: added the table definition.

Comment: Looks like this is bug. I made a little research and found this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-19152. Fixed version is 2.2.0. Unfortunately I can’t verify it, cause my company’s cluster uses version 2.1.0.

Comment: Could you please write an answer so that i will accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is bug. I made a little research and found this issue [SPARK-19152](http://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-19152). Fixed version is 2.2.0. Unfortunately I can’t verify it, cause my company’s cluster uses version 2.1.0